# set Date & time regular expression to RegularExpressionValidator according to culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, cultureinfo, culture

I am facing a problem of validating date & time according to local culture.

This is my RegularExpressionValidator

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
       ID="regTime"
       ControlToValidate="txtTime"
       Display="Dynamic"
       Text="Invalid Time Format"
       ValidationExpression="^((1[012])|(0?[1-9])):([0-5][0-9]) ?([aApP][mM])$"
       runat="server">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The above validator validates time of en-en culture.

Now as I am developing an applications which needs to be able to handle date and time format of every culture, I want a concrete solution to how to validate date & time depending on culture using RegularExpression.

For example, American time format is h:mm tt (01:20 PM) & German time format is HH:mm (13:20).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but this reminds me of the popular quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Anyway, you don't need regular expressions for this. .NET's DateTime and CultureInfo are best suited to solve this. Create your own custom validator that does something like the following:

```
var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
DateTime.ParseExact("3:20 PM", usCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern, usCulture);

var germanCulture = new CultureInfo("de");
DateTime.ParseExact("13:20", germanCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern, germanCulture);
```

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` if you want a return value instead of an exception.

Comment: As this question is about asp.net, he might want to transfer the regex to javascript to validate the date format, in that case this solution would not help?